# Web API - Request.CreateResponse with HttpStatusCode.BadRequest causing Internal server error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am having an issue with the following line of code in my project. I am using Web API on Windows 2008 R2, with IIS 7.5.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request");
```

However, this command works perfectly:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Ok Response");
```

Any idea why this is happenning?

Controller Code:

```
[Throttle(Name = "ProductCtrl", Count = 10, Seconds = 10)]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    [ActionName("Current-ProductName")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetCurrentProductName(string id)
    {
      // I added this code to test also but I can see the log but it return  
      // Internal server error instead  Bad Request
       Log.Info("Test");
       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request");

        try
        {

            //Codes to get the data .....

            var productName = "My productName";
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, productName);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log the Errors...

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request");
        }

    }


}
```

in WebApi.Config

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ProductCtrlWithAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/productInfo/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "All", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Calling from Fiddler 
/Api/ProductInfo/Current-ProductName/1001

Comment: What is the problem actually with this response status? As I can't see whole code I can suppose that condition for return such status just not matching. Like this pseudo code: if (model.IsValid != true) {return badrequest};

Comment: Hi Andrey, The actual problem is that when i returning Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad Request") giving Internal Server Error. The Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, productName) only giving me the correct httpstatus code other than this all giving me Internal Server Error even with one line of code.  Sorry if my reply make you confused. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I changed my return to this: `return BadRequest();` it worked again.